# Can I get referenced projects code using Source Generators?

Tags: c#, code-generation, sourcegenerators

I started playing with the C# source generators and I'm trying to read the code that it's not in the actual project but in the referenced projects.

Is it possible?

Comment: Any luck with this? I've been stuck on this for a few days and haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: If you found a solution, can you please post.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax nodes of referenced projects will not be passed to the analyzer of the dependent project. In fact, that might not even be theoretically possible, considering you might not have the source code/symbol files available for the external assemblies. If you indeed *have* the source available, why not run the analyzer directly there?

Or are you just trying to resolve some external type being referenced from within your "analyzed" project? Official guidelines sort of forbids any I/O in the generator context, but I guess there is dark magic for everything...